# How to efficiently change member data of all objects in a vector?

Tags: c++, performance, vector, c++17

Given a `vector` of pointers to class objects, what are the "preferred" (most efficient/performant/concise) methods of changing the objects' member data in modern C++? Of course, I can use a `for` loop to iterate over the `vector`, but would using `for_each` with a lambda expression be a better alternative? Are there other ways that are even better?

As an example, let us suppose we have `vector<Person*> successfulPeople` with the `Person` class containing two member variable bools `isHappy` and `isRich` that need to be changed from `false` to `true` for all `Person` objects in `successfulPeople`.

Comment: Why do you think anything is going to be more performant than a for loop?

Comment: ranged-for is the "best" because it's the easiest to maintain

Comment: @MooingDuck Not sure, which is why I was asking. At least in `Mathematica`, using the `for` loop is largely discouraged, as there are significantly faster alternatives. Was wondering if the same might be true in C++.

Comment: Well, a partially unrolled loop, or SIMD, or parallel (threaded) loop can all be more efficient than a naive loop.  But C++ optimizers are very good at transforming the code (they can perform unrolling and SIMD automatically, and parallel loops with only a little `#pragma omp parallel`), and if you have to ask this question, the compiler is almost surely better at optimizing it than you would be.

Comment: @BenVoigt what about std::transform with a lambda?  Is that less maintainable than a ranged for loop?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: `std::transform` takes care of keeping two iterators advancing in sync.  There's no such value added by `std::for_each`.  (Even with `std::transform`, that value probably doesn't justify the extra complexity of a lambda, and manually handling of iterators for the source sequence)

Comment: I honestly don't understand why this question is getting downvoted, and it's not particularly helpful to have downvotes without any explanations. How does that help someone improve, if there are any issues that aren't actually pointed out and explained?

Comment: @PhysicsCodingEnthusiast: There's nothing to improve. The very foundation of your question is a premature optimization. Write your code in a correct and reasonably straightforward/idiomatic way; if it proves to be too slow, then figure out where it's too slow and then deal with that. Indeed, my biggest concern about your code is not the kind of loop; it's the fact that you're looping over an array of *pointers* to this data, which is more likely than not going to kill cache coherency. If this were performance critical code, then step 1 is to use a `vector<Person>` directly.

Comment: @NicolBolas I already have a complete, working code, and have questions about a few aspects, and wanted to hone in on areas I thought I could improve – hence, this question. Again, one reason is because I am used to `for` loops being discouraged in `Mathematica` code, so I was curious about it. I feel that there really is stifling of curiosity and shaming of asking what are considered "simple"/"obvious" questions, which is really unfortunate. The reason for vectors of pointers is because I have a main vector of unique pointers, and this is a vector that contains a subset of the objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, `for_each` is more preferable as it allows to specify its execution policy:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <execution>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{0, 1, 2};
    std::for_each(std::par_unseq, v.begin(), v.end(), [](int &x){ x += 40; });
}
```

In reality, if you try to compile the code above, current compilers will refuse to:

```
$ clang -v -std=c++17 meow.cpp |& gawk '/execution/ { on = 1 } on || NR == 1 { print }' | sed 's/^/    /'
clang version 6.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
meow.cpp:5:10: fatal error: 'execution' file not found
#include <execution>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

$ g++ -v meow.cpp |& tail -9 | sed 's/^/    /'
GNU C++17 (GCC) version 8.1.1 20180531 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 8.1.1 20180531, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.1, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.19-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: c1584951f18917e503c3b4657c1f0dc5
meow.cpp:5:10: fatal error: execution: No such file or directory
 #include <execution>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

as Parallelism TS is probably not yet on the on the current priorities list (despite many C++20 feature are.)

As for `for` loops, [there is no standard attribute that specifies parallel/otherwise non-sequential loop execution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes), but clang, for instance, [provides pragmas to optimize loops](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#extensions-for-loop-hint-optimizations).

So, despite current standard suggests `for_each` can (probably) perform better, current realistic choice is actually a `for`-loop with `pragma`s. :-\

Comment: Thanks for the response! Definitely some interesting, new content in your answer that I haven't encountered before. Will have to read up more on `for_each`'s execution policy.

Comment: Well, as I said, I haven't seen it implemented anywhere yet, so your reading will be a long-term investment. :-\

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any. `for` loop and `for each` are just doing the same thing but with different syntax. If you're just searching the container for one element, other data structures like binary tree might be more efficient but no matter which container, as long as you need to loop through the entire data structure, the complexity is going to be O(n). Of course, even though the complexity is the same, depending on how the data structure is stored (i.e. in contiguous memory), the speed is going to be different.

Comment: When two algorithms have the same complexity order (e.g., O(n) in this case), then the prefactors become important: it wouldn't ever be a bad thing to reduce a specific operation/calculation by a factor of 2 or 4 :-)

Comment: @AnInquiringMind Yes that's true. However, if you're just doing simple boolean state update like your example, you can't get much faster unless you multi-thread your program, unless that's the answer you're looking for. Even for some complex arithmetic calculations, even using SIMD might not be faster since SIMD heavily depends on parallel computation to decrease the time so if your calculations are not independent, then there's not much help.